# Using Cloudflare SSL certificate for Subdomain with www

Tags: ssl, cdn, cloudflare

I am looking to have a solution for using Cloudflare Dedicated SSL certificate for my website subdomains. I have purchased the $10/month package with the expectation that I could setup a wildcard hostname with the www.

I want my subdomains to load with the SSL certificate and I have more than 100 subdomains available for my domain. I don’t want to add each subdomain with www as a hostname but use a wildcard format.

I am inspired after reading the following posts -

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/page-rule-forwarding-with-subdomain-and-wildcards/136977
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/subdomain-too-deep/81872

My current hostnames are -

`.example.com, example.com,  .www.example.com`

I added `*.www.example.com` to work for subdomains like `www.sub.example.com` but it seems not working! I think the wildcard format is incorrect.

I want my SSL certificate works for all addresses like below. -

```
example.com
www.example.com
sub1.example.com
www.sub2.example.com
sub2.example.com
www.sub2.example.com
```

I am quite confused if it's really possible with Cloudflare!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As reported on the [Cloudflare Support article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203295200-End-to-end-HTTPS-with-Cloudflare-Part-2-SSL-certificates)

> Dedicated certificates with Custom Hostnames can cover additional levels of subdomains (ex: test.dev.www.example.com instead of just [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))

So you should be able to create a Dedicated Certificate which covers
`example.com *.example.com *.sub1.example.com *.sub2.example.com`, which should work for:

```
example.com
www.example.com
foo.example.com
www.sub1.example.com
bar.sub1.example.com
baz.sub2.example.com
www.sub2.example.com
[...]
```

And so on. In your message, you mention adding `*.www.example.com` to the certificate to cover for subdomains like `www.sub.example.com` - but this does not look correct, as you would need `*.sub.example.com` added instead.